# Can read-write race conditions in an OpenCL kernel lead to corrupted data?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

Consider a pair of OpenCL kernels which read and write to the same memory locations. As a simple example, consider the following OpenCL program:

```
__kernel void k1(__global int * a)
{
    a[0] = 2*a[1];
}

__kernel void k2(__global int * a)
{
    a[1] = a[0]-1;
}
```

If many threads are launched, running many of each of these kernels, the resulting state of global memory is non-deterministic.

This still potentially allows one to write asynchronous algorithms which accept any of the possible orderings of the operations within the kernels.

However, this requires that **reads and writes to global GPU memory are atomic**.

My questions are

- Is this guaranteed to be true on any current GPGPU hardware?
- If this considered undefined behavior by the OpenCL standard? If so, what do common implementations (specifically that included with the CUDA toolkit) do?
- How can one test this concern?

Comment: why do you have two kernels with the same name? anyway, memory reads are not atomic.

Comment: Thanks, typo fixed. Can you be more precise? What do you mean exactly by "memory reads are not atomic"? That they are not guaranteed by the OpenCL standard to be atomic? That they are not atomic on any existing hardware? Can you point to a reference of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

If you enqueue your kernel commands to a single command queue that is created as an *in-order* queue (i.e. you didn't specify `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE` when you created it), then only one kernel command will execute at a time. This means that you won't have any such issues between different kernel instances (although you could still have race conditions between work-items in a single kernel instance, if they are accessing the same memory locations).

If you are using out-of-order queues, or multiple command-queues, then you may indeed have a race condition. There is no guarantee that your load-modify-store sequence will be an atomic operation, and this will cause undefined behaviour.

Depending on what you actually want to do with your kernels, you may be able to make use of OpenCL's built-in atomic functions, which do allow you to perform a particular set of read-modify-write operations in an atomic manner.

Comment: My question is not about load-modify-store sequences being atomic, but rather reads and writes themselves being atomic.